# Using Alias defined in webpack for client side react rendering but having issue

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

Using Alias defined in webpack for client side react rendering but when trying to render on Node server using Express having issue.

I have defined some alias in webpack example

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.cjsx', '.coffee', '.json'],
    alias: {
      pages: path.join(__dirname, 'js/MGPages.js'),
    }
  },
```

but when require my main app file on node server I am getting below error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'pages'
```

Client side alias works fine but how can I solve this problem on node server side. I don't want to change the code of importing file on my react component for client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not webpacking the files that node runs (for example if you're using `babel-register` instead), then the alias won't apply.

If you want to do something like `import pages from 'pages'` without having to specify a path you might need to use something like [rewrite-modules](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-fbjs/plugins/rewrite-modules.js) (which is what React does internally).